# Handlebars instead of Sightly HTL

Tags: handlebars.js, aem, aem-6

Can I use the handlebars to build my components for a website, if yes what are the limitations of using Handlebars over Sightly?

Is it advisable to create my own handlebar scripting engine or I can use the one being used for SCF? If I use AEM Communities Handlebars Scripting Engine is there any licensing complication that I need to be aware of?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Comment: As @Bebs stated you should post multiple question on specific subjects. Also avoid asking opinion based questions.

Comment: @Bebs Thank you for the suggestion but the three questions that I have raised are very relevant to the topic in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use handlebars to build your component. One key difference between handlebars and HTl (Sightly) is that HTl is server-side templating while handlebars can be used on both serverside and clientside.